# Python Scipy Interpolate Griddata - How do i extract X,Y,Z data out griddata based interpolation in Python

Tags: python, scipy

I have a set of x,y,z data on an irregular grid. I tried to interpolate the same on a regular grid using griddata. Now, how can i extract the output (X,Y,Z) to a file in Python. Any help is much appreciated.

The code is as shown below

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy.ma as ma
from numpy.random import uniform
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import griddata
# Read data from an existing dataframe 
x = df['X']
y = df['Y']
z = df['WD']
# define grid.
xi = np.linspace(-4900,6000,100)
yi = np.linspace(-5200,7700,100)
# grid the data.
zi = griddata((x, y), z, (xi[None,:], yi[:,None]), method='cubic')

xn=[]
yn=[]

l=1
for i in range(0, len(xi)):
    for j in range(0, len(yi)):
            xn[l]=xi[i]
            yn[l]=yi[j]
            l=l+1
d = np.vstack((xn,yn,zi))
np.savetxt("file.csv", d, delimiter=",", fmt='% 4d')
```

Apparently this method works tills extracting the zi values using griddata, and not beyond that.
I am trying to extract the xi,yi,zi from the griddata and write this information to a file to be used by another program.

Can anyone advice on how to go about it?

Comment: Aren't `xi` and `yi` *inputs* to `griddata`? That is, you can't "extract' them from `griddata`, you already have them.

Comment: Yes and No. I am trying to figure out how to output/pair  (xi,yi) with zi from the griddata so that i could piece together an array (xi,yi,zi).

Comment: Are `xi` and `yi` actually correct (shape-size, mainly)? Usually, one uses something like `np.mgrid` to create the x and y grid to interpolate on.